# ILPlotPanel Component in UserControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, ilnumerics

I'm having a problem trying to embed an ILPlotPanel inside a
UserControl which will be used as a COM Component, and will be imported by
a third part software.

I can put the ILPanel, but it don't render nothing (keeps the design mode visualization).
In another hand the ILPlotPanel gives me a error while trying do click and drag it (VS2010) to
a empty UserControl.

Here's the given error:

[image]

So the problems are:

1°. ILPanel don't render scenes while hosted by another application.

2º. In VS2010, can't click and drag the ILPlotPanel to a UserControl.

So anyone have a clue on this issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use ILPanel instead of ILPlotPanel?

Comment: Yes, i did. Works but keeps showing the design mode view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ILNumerics.Settings.IsHosted property! You can set it via code (if your Host allows it early enough) or via configuration (by using the key `ILNIsHosted`).

Comment: Looking at the Object Browser there are no ILNumerics.Settings.IsHosted. I'm currently using ILNumerics32 (v3.1.0.0). Am i missing something? Edit: Looking at the 3.2.2 changelog i see why. :-)

Comment: Right. Take the current version. It would be great if you could mark it as the answer ;)